# Select equal values from one column, with different values in second column

Tags: rstudio

I have a large dataframe in R looking like this:

BCountry  BNr

DE        1

DE        1

DE        1

FR        2

FR        2

PL        2

How can I exclude all rows, where the B.Nr is equal, but the BCountry is not.
So my desired result would be

BCountry BNr

FR       2

FR       2

PL       2

I appreciate any help :))